# Swift CollectionView.reload data not working when data changes in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase

I currently have this working code which reads from a `users` location in Firebase which contains all the user profile information for each user. I am using the snapshot (data) returned from Firebase to build my array and display users in a `CollectionView`.

The behaviour that I expected (which is not happening) is that when a value for a `user` property changes in Firebase (eg; `online` status changes to 'offline') this should then be pushed down to my app so that the `CollectionView` is updated and therefore not display the user that just went "offline".

Am I using the correct Firebase query below?

```
self.REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value , with: { (snapshot) in

                    guard let usersSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

                    for user in usersSnapshot{

                        let discoverable = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "discoverable").value as! Bool

                        if user.key == key && discoverable == true {

                            let uid = user.key
                            let name = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
                            let email = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
                            let profilePictureURL = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "profilePictureURL").value as! String

                            let birthday = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "birthday").value as! String
                            let firstName = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "firstName").value as! String
                            let lastName = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "lastName").value as! String
                            let gender = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "gender").value as! String
                            let discoverable = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "discoverable").value as! Bool
                            let online = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "online").value as! Bool

                            let discoveryPrefs = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "discoveryPrefs").value as! [String : Any]

                            let dictionary: [String : Any] = ["uid": uid, "name": name, "email": email, "profilePictureURL": profilePictureURL, "birthday": birthday, "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "gender": gender, "discoverable": discoverable, "online": online, "discoveryPrefs": discoveryPrefs]

                            let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)

                            users.append(user)

                        }//end if

                    }//end for

                    //filter out "remove" current user from array
                    let filteredUsers = users.filter({ (user: User) -> Bool in return !user.uid.contains(uid) })

                    handler(filteredUsers.shuffled(), true)//return a shuffled version of the array via handler

                })//end FIR snapshot call
```

This is how I use the code above to load/reload data:

```
DataService.run.getUsersAtVenue(forVenueLocation: location, forUid: userId) { (users, successBool) in

            if successBool {
                self.users = users
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                Utilities.run.dismissSVHUD(delay: 0.5)

            }
        }
```

Comment: what are you getting from `online` when user went offline? `True/False`?

Comment: I am currently changing the value of `discoverable` to either `true` or `false`, this field specifies if the user should be displayed on the collectionview. The same for `online` its either `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Are you in main thread, and `users` changed? Try to put it in:

```
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if users.count > 0 {
                      self.users = users
                      self.collectionView.reloadData()
                      Utilities.run.dismissSVHUD(delay: 0.5)
                }  
        }
```

Comment: This loads the collectioview but it doesn't update when the data changes in Firebase.

Comment: Comment your load method and just assign `users` value to test if your collection view works well. If no problem, uncomment the load method then check the potential reason could be loaded more than once, and your users variable.count isn't 0 but for next round call it was set to `nil` or whatever. Can you check how many times your load user method was called?

Answer (score 0):

Roggie, you need to register an observer to receive a notification whenever a specific 'User' node (a child under the 'users' location) changes. The code for this should look similar to below

```
_refHandleUserChanged = ref.child("users").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
    guard let changedUserIndex = self.userSnapshots.index {$0.key == snapshot.key} else { return }
    self.userSnapshots[changedUserIndex] = snapshot
    self.userCollectionView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: changedUserIndex, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
})
```

where 'ref' is the reference to your Firebase database, and '_refHandleUserChanged' is an instance var property of your current class (maybe your View Controller class). Then you should unregister/remove this observer when your instance is de-initialized like the following code.

```
deinit {
    ref.child("users").removeObserver(withHandle: _refHandleUserChanged)
}
```

Comment: Your feedback on registering an 'observer' makes sense. I'm just trying to get my head around the changes required to my code. Do I need to add the "observer" part to my `cellForItemAt`? if no then where?. Also, would `var 
 _refHandleUserChanged ` be an instance of my current ViewController which is called `DiscoverVC`?. Are you able to point me to some online tutorials perhaps?

Comment: Does your DiscoverVC conform to UICollectionViewDataSource? If so, you should create in DiscoverVC class a separate method, for example called configureDatabase, which contains "ref = Database.database().reference()" and the "observer registration" code above. Then you call this method within the viewDidLoad method. And of cause you need to declare "ref" & "_refHandleUserChanged" as var properties of DiscoverVC class, like this: "private var ref: DatabaseReference!" & "private var _refHandleUserChanged: DatabaseHandle!"

Comment: `DiscoverVC` does conform to `UICollectionViewDataSource`, I have created the suggested function, but I am getting an error `Use of unresolved identifier '_refHandleUserChanged'`. What should this var be?. As well as `Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments; did you mean 'snapshot'?` `Replace '$0' with 'snapshot'`

Comment: '_refHandleUserChanged' should be declared at the top of DiscoverVC class like this 'private var ref: DatabaseReference!'. Please note that, I assume that you have the var property 'userSnapshots' loaded with user records from your Firebase database. Then this property is used as data source to populate your CollectionView. You can check out this short yet helpful course https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-ios--ud0351

Answer (score 0):

What I do for small data sets is at the completion of the completionBlock after you have all the new data.

Is the topViewController the CollectionView
If it is cast it to the custom a collectionView
Then call collectionview.reloadData.

All of that is embedded into the main queue.

It’s highly likely that you are reloading prior to getting the data back